# What is the hit effect multiplier in Campaign 1 for a Me-210?

Tags: target-for-today

In campaign 1, I got result 45 my next wave after bombing Paris.  The Me-210 coming in from 9 High was piloted by an Ace and got me good for 3 hits.

However on table 5-11 the only entry for a Me-210 is for campaigns 3-6.  Should this entry be used for campaign 1 as well?

Answer (score 1):

In the [errata](http://www.stevenkdixon.com/v1_9_TFT_Tables.pdf) posted last year, this table has been fixed to apply for campaigns 1-6.